# Pre-process html content with browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, plugins, browser

Unfortunately, for some special purpose, some domain was disabled by the *GOVERNMENT FIREWALL*

For example: any domain name `*.gg.com` was unreachable through http.

The problem is, many websites request sources from this domain, this inconvenience make many websites frequently used loading extremely slow.

---

There is solution, because the shielding is only on the domain, but not on the ip, so if I use a `cname` record to the domain, the contents can load!

**For example:**

If I want to request `http://script.gg.com/jquery.js`

I can set `script.mydomain.com` CNAME to `script.gg.com`

And request `http://script.mydomain.com/jquery.js` is good.

---

I want to use this feature automatically on my browser. I mainly use Google Crome.

I'm wondering if there is a way to pre-process the html the browser loaded, and replace all resource link domain, mapping from the banned list to a valid list?

I might thought there can be a plugin or something else, find or develop myself, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can preprocess it with javascript.

Firefox has greasemonkey plugin, but I think Chrome probably has something similar. This javascript is executed at the very beginning of page load and maybe you can replace the urls with some javascript and thus making browser load the replaced urls instead of those written in actual code.

Update:
Chrome has Tampermonkey.

Tested with the script and it worked okay:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
     links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(".google.", ".bing.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning on the plugin, I think it might help!